# Strange bar plot alignment in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm generating a bar plot in pandas using the following commands (where x is an existing DataFrame):

```
df = x.groupby(['pAlt']).describe()['win_stay'].unstack()
df['se'] = df['std']/np.sqrt(df['count']) # calculate standard error
df['mean'].plot(kind='bar',yerr=df.se,alpha=0.5,ax=ax,legend=False)
```

The plot generally looks right, except for the position of the bars:

[image]

For some reason they're butted up against the right edge of the plot, rather than being centered. This appears to be a new issue introduced in Pandas 0.14: If I downgrade to 0.13.1 and run the exact same code, the plot looks like this:

[image]

Any simple workarounds other than sticking with the downgraded version of pandas?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This might be related to [this bug in matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2150), affecting some versions < 1.4.0. (I'm seeing it in version 1.3.1).</strike>

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

print(pd.__version__)
# 0.14.0
print(mpl.__version__)    
# 1.3.1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'mean': [0.25, 0.2, 0.25]}, index=[0.5, 0.8, 0.85])
df['mean'].plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.5, legend=False, ax=ax)

ax.set_xlim(-1, len(df['mean']))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, @unutbu, the plot graphic you posted doesn't appear to match what the code you posted does ... I've got matplotlib 1.3.1 and I get something similar to the first plot in the question, as your text implies.  And I think you may be right, but what to do about I'm not sure.

Comment: Same here. Copy/pasted your code and my plot looks more like the first in my question, see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2rihv7holq0j0t/Screenshot%202014-07-03%2014.31.21.png.

Comment: But my question remains: Is there a workaround here or should I just downgrade Pandas for now?

Comment: @moustachio: Hm, I'm sorry but I don't know why you are seeing a different result. With pandas version 0.14.0 and matplotlib 1.3.1, I get the plot posted above.

Comment: If it helps, I was using pandas 0.12.0

Comment: I don't think this is related to that bug, which is triggered when the bars on the ends are zero height and are ignored in the auto-scaling.  This is a bug in pandas, not mpl

Comment: @tcaswell Yep, and this is confirmed by the fact that by upgrading to the latest release of pandas (0.14.1) the issue is resolved.