# Series bar graph edge cut-off in iPython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I plot a series in iPython Notebook with pandas, the bars are all shifted to the right:

```
import pylab as pl
from pandas import *

x = Series({0: 1, 1: 3, 2:2.5})

x.plot(kind="bar")
```

[image: off-center bar in plot]

(Note: I don't think they used to be plotted off-center like this in iPython Notebook, I only noticed this recently when I opened up an older workbook).

Is there a quick fix to center the bars using this plotting format? I know I can mannually set their positions, width etc, but I prefer to keep this code.

Comment: You may be experiencing the same thing as in this question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/24540016/strange-bar-plot-alignment-in-pandas/24540243. What version are you using?

Comment: Pandas = 0.14.0, Pylab = 1.8.0, matplotlib = 1.3.1. Yeah, it looks like the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540016/strange-bar-plot-alignment-in-pandas/245402‌​43 <-- fixed link